# How to read audio stream in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I just want to read some audio stream for example from http://livestream.rfn.ru:8080/kulturafm/mp3_192kbps. My code is like this

```
http = require('http')

options = 
  host: 'livestream.rfn.ru'
  path: ':8080/kulturafm/mp3_192kbps'

callback = (res) ->
  res.on 'data', (chunk) -> console.log String(chunk)
  res.on 'end', -> console.log('No more data in response.')

http.request(options, callback).end()
```

Output is:

> <html><head><title>Wowza Streaming Engine 4 Monthly Edition 4.4.0 build17748</title></head><body>Wowza Streaming Engine 4 Monthly Edition 4.4.0 build17748</body></html>

No more data in response.  I can't understand how to get data from the MP3 stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're putting the port (`8080`) in the path.  This is incorrect.  Your HTTP client is connecting to port `80` instead, as a default.

You don't need to specify the options object in this way.  Just pass the URL and it will parse for you.  Use `http.get()` and it will set the appropriate verb and `.end()` for you.

```
var streamUrl = 'http://livestream.rfn.ru:8080/kulturafm/mp3_192kbps';
http.get(streamUrl, callback);
```

Comment: Oh stupid me! Thanks! Another way is to add port: 8080 to options and remove it from path. I just overlooked port property in documentation.

Comment: @hagent Yeah, it's just the `port` option.  https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback